# Getting 'No such file' error when trying to download a file with Renci.SshNet using SftpClient

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ssh.net

It works when I download a file from another server. I can delete files and get a directory list but I cannot download the file. The only exception I get is 'No such file', even when I use a file returned from a ListDirectory call. The server that works has SSH keys installed and the server that doesn't does not have SSH keys installed. Does Renci.SshNet only ftp from servers with SSH installed?

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string host = "ether4";

        string pathLocalFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "factor_out.txt");

        using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(host, _username, _password))
        {
            try
            {
                sftp.Connect();
                var files = sftp.ListDirectory("/factor/dktest/pdi");
                sftp.ChangeDirectory("/factor/dktest/pdi");
                Debug.Print(sftp.WorkingDirectory);                     // <-- /factor/dktest/pdi
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(pathLocalFile))
                    {
                        //if (!file.Name.StartsWith("."))
                        //    sftp.DownloadFile(file.Name, fileStream); // <-- Exception thrown here

                        if (!file.FullName.EndsWith("."))
                        {
                            sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);   // <-- Exception thrown here
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                sftp.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception has been caught " + er.ToString()); // No Such File
            }
        }
    }
```

The full error message is "No such file".
There is no InnerException. HResult = -2146233088.

```
file.FullName = "/factor/dktest/pdi/gl_accounts.txt"

StackTrace
   at Renci.SshNet.Common.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.EndOpen(SftpOpenAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Renci.SshNet.ServiceFactory.CreateSftpFileReader(String fileName, ISftpSession sftpSession, UInt32 bufferSize)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.InternalDownloadFile(String path, Stream output, SftpDownloadAsyncResult asyncResult, Action`1 downloadCallback)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.DownloadFile(String path, Stream output, Action`1 downloadCallback)
   at FtpTesting.frmSshNet.button7_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\\Development\\FtpTesting\\FtpTesting\\frmSshNet.cs:line 98"
```

Comment: What is value of `file.FullName` when the exception occurs? + Show us full exception callstack and error message.

Comment: I installed FluentFTP and used it and it worked fine. I was hoping to have one set  of code for SFTP and FTP but if I need to, I'll use two.

Comment: I'm lost. FluentFTP is **FTP** client. SSH.NET is **SFTP** client. How could you replace SSH.NET with FluentFTP?

Comment: I wanted to use Ssh.NET for both FTP and SFTP. Part of my question is if this was possible (I could find nothing stating that it was not possible). I was able to run commands, navigate the file system and delete files with SSH.NET, it just fails to download a file. If it turns out it is not possible, I will have to have my application be able to use both. I will probably have the user check a box in a setting form.

Comment: SSH.NET is SSH/SFTP library. FTP is a completely unrelated protocol. You cannot expect a library to document what protocols it *does not support*.

Comment: Can you download those files using the same credentials using any SFTP client? (even GUI one)

Comment: Martin Prikryl - If you post your comment that SSH.NET does not support the FTP protocol I will make that as the answer. Sorry, I'm new to this and it's hard to find any clear documentation on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question [ftp](/questions/tagged/ftp), but your are using SFTP code.

While it's not really an answer to your immediate problem, it seems that you actually need to use FTP. Your SFTP server is possibly broken somehow.

SSH.NET does not support FTP. You can use .NET `FtpWebRequest` or some 3rd  party FTP client library.